# How can I make this pyramid more pointy?

Tags: ruby

This ruby code generates a pyramid:

```
w = 20
1.upto(w) { |i| puts ">"+" "*(w-i)+"."*i*2+" "*(w-i)+"<" }
```

Like so:

```
>                   ..                   <
>                  ....                  <
>                 ......                 <
>                ........                <
>               ..........               <
>              ............              <
>             ..............             <
>            ................            <
>           ..................           <
>          ....................          <
>         ......................         <
>        ........................        <
>       ..........................       <
>      ............................      <
>     ..............................     <
>    ................................    <
>   ..................................   <
>  ....................................  <
> ...................................... <
>........................................<
```

I want to make the pyramid have one dot at the top instead of two (currently because of `"."*i*2` to make it symmetrical).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `"."*(i*2-1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
w=20; 1.upto(w) { |i| puts ">"+" "*(w-i)+"."*(i*2-1)+" "*(w-i)+"<" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a fixed-width font, so there's no way to get a period centered above your current pyramid.  You need to use odd numbers of dots rather than even numbers:

```
w = 20
1.upto(w) do |i|
  spaces = " " * (w-i)
  dots   = "." * (i*2 - 1) # Use one fewer dot per line, starting with one dot
  puts ">" + spaces + dots + spaces + "<"
end
```

This produces:

```
>                   .                   <
>                  ...                  <
>                 .....                 <
>                .......                <
>               .........               <
>              ...........              <
>             .............             <
>            ...............            <
>           .................           <
>          ...................          <
>         .....................         <
>        .......................        <
>       .........................       <
>      ...........................      <
>     .............................     <
>    ...............................    <
>   .................................   <
>  ...................................  <
> ..................................... <
>.......................................<
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `times` will make it cleaner. Also, there is `center` that simplifies things:

```
20.times{|i| puts ">#{("."*(i*2+1)).center(39)}<"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
S, W = ' ', 20; 1.upto(W) {|i| n = W - i; puts ">#{S*n + '.' * (2*i - 1) + S*n}<"}
```